# suspend pthread?

Tags: c, multithreading, suspend

I want to implement a mutex lock.
From my understanding, mutex.lock() should work like 
1) check lock owner
2) if lock is owned, put thread in waiting queue
3) suspend this thread until another thread send a wait up signal

However, there is nothing like pthread_suspend(), then how do I do suspend?
I found someone saying use pthread_con_wait(), but seems if I want to use that function, I have to set up a pthread_mutex lock first, which it doesn't make sense to use pthread_mutex inside my mutex.

Well, if my understanding of mutex is wrong, please correct me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mutex.lock() should work like:

1) check lock owner 
2) if lock is owned, put thread in waiting queue 
3) suspend this thread until THE THREAD THAT OWNS THE LOCK sends a wake up signal.  No other thread can release the lock.

These steps should be performed as an atomic operation so that the correct behaviour is followed for all threads acquiring/releasing the mutex, no matter how such calls may be interrupted and reentered from other threads.

'However, there is nothing like pthread_suspend(), then how do I do suspend?' - usually, you don't.  The OS kernel provides synchronization primitives that can block threads that should not run on.  To implement a 'suspend' in user-space, you can only spin-wait - something that is a good strategy in a few cases, (underloaded multi-core box where the lock is only held for a very short time), but certainly not all, (and can lead to spectacularly disastrous livelocks across whole clusters of machines).

If you want a mutex, use an OS mutex - that's what any cross-platform lib. will do.

Comment: then what does spin-wait check (after the thread is inserted into Q)?  like this? "while(lockOwner != self)" then what's the difference between this and spin lock...

Answer (score 2):

Mutexes, locks, and wait conditions are all different, distinct things. You need a mutex variable in order to *implement* both a lock and a wait condition.

A lock is a simple mechanism that prevents more than one thread from executing the same code at once by making all by one thread wait for the lock to become unlocked.

A wait condition is a slightly more complex structure that allows a thread to monitor a condition (usually a boolean flag) and only wake up when the flag has changed favourably.

In both cases, when a thread blocks (i.e. sleeps), the operating system's scheduling primitives automatically take care of descheduling the thread and using the available computing time elsewhere. Thread and task scheduling is not something you would normally have to worry about manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can only make things that are at least as complex as the simplest pieces you have. If the simplest pieces you have *are* mutexes, then you can't make mutexes from the pieces you have. You can only make things at least as complex as a mutex or more so. If you have any pieces simpler than a mutex, tell us what they are, and we can tell you how to make a mutex out of them.

I suppose, if you want, you can make your own mutex out of pthread mutexes and condition variables. I'm not sure what the point is, but it's trivial to do. As you noted, you can use `pthread_cond_wait` to wait on your own kind of mutex.

The reason the pthreads standard gives you a mutex is because it's about the most flexible of the possible synchronization primitives.